# TypeScript: Constant array as type definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a typescript project and struggle a bit with defining a fitting type.
Context:

I got the following constant inside my project:

```
export const PROPERTYOPTIONS = [
  { value: "tag", label: "Tag" }, 
  { value: "composition", label: "Composition" },
  { value: "solvent", label: "Solvent" },
  { value: "allergen", label: "Allergen" },
  { value: "category", label: "Category" },
  { value: "other", label: "Other" },
];
```

Now I want to define an interface:

```
interface CreatePropertyModalState {
  type: { value: string; label: string };
}
```

How can I define that the type of the type field is a member of PROPERTYOPTIONS?

I want to dodge a type definition like:

```
type: { value: "tag" | "composition" | .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not planning to change the contents of `PROPERTYOPTIONS` at runtime, you can mark it as immutable (`as const`) and define a type alias for it using `typeof`:

```
export const PROPERTYOPTIONS = [
  { value: 'tag', label: 'Tag' }, 
  { value: 'composition', label: 'Composition' },
  { value: 'solvent', label: 'Solvent' },
  { value: 'allergen', label: 'Allergen' },
  { value: 'category', label: 'Category' },
  { value: 'other', label: 'Other' },
] as const

type PropertyOptions = typeof PROPERTYOPTIONS
type PropertyOption = PropertyOption[number]
interface CreatePropertyModalState {
  // if the type should be exactly one of the options
  type: PropertyOption,
  // if you want to combine an allowed value with an arbitrary label
  type: { value: PropertyOption['value'], label: string },
}
```

Comment: That you for the fast answer! This solved the issue and looks pretty clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic identity function to constrain the type of the array, and then `typeof` with an indexed access type to extract the type you want.

```
function checkArray<T extends string>(arr: {value: T, label: string}[]) {
    return arr;
}

export const PROPERTY_OPTIONS = checkArray([
  { value: "tag", label: "Tag" }, 
  { value: "composition", label: "Composition" },
  { value: "solvent", label: "Solvent" },
  { value: "allergen", label: "Allergen" },
  { value: "category", label: "Category" },
  { value: "other", label: "Other" },
]);

type PropertyOption = typeof PROPERTY_OPTIONS[number]
// type PropertyOption = {
//     value: "tag" | "composition" | "solvent" | "allergen" | "category" | "other";
//     label: string;
// }

interface CreatePropertyModalState {
    type: PropertyOption
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawIICdcCGAngDwAqiaAHlGmACYDOijUuMYA5gHwAUB+AFyIA3gDcCAGxBphZADSJJBAEZpJw1uy4BfANoBdAJSiAUIguJcaKCFxIBuANymdp09QAOcXFGQJWRAAFACUAeSCAURCyAE0AfQiyAEkwgDkAZUQAXmR0LDxCIl49c1FECWlZRAAiKAJOGsVlNQ1asgaaxB1FMpEKqRlhGog4AFtvRhhYBCalVXVhgGFxyen4MC6evoGq4cY4STE6KDmWxdqMw+OwU+75Hcqh2qlJNFxOOjOFtprsSTeHy+90eg2qIwItE4PiI31ay0haGhuFhIIs-Se4LgUHQuDhFxqYRx7y2D2MLlMUCInjQwVwcBpviIYU8MyQuSpNLgwGC4SiMQSSVSmT0YBAYzUuAMpgA9DLEJzaUF6YyqSy2TkzHLLBZMcN6o1EAAfWqjCZwKZsrommoHI4na0vAHvT6bY2mxHI1E27G4moubU685tLQcTgB+VuIA)